# provider lock router access. Automatically my wireless 2nd router adapts and change address to 192.168.0.1 (BAD!)!

Tags: router, provider

my cable ISP router have address 192.168.1.1, I can’t change that setting because provider lock router access. Automatically my wireless 2nd router adapts and change address to 192.168.0.1, and also my DHCP address range to 192.168.0.100 - 192.168.0.199
that IP rang change affected my NVR and IP cameras now not to be seen on the network. All port forwards are automatically disabled because of this also.
I don’t want to change all the address. how can I get back the original IP range back on my second Router? (192.168.1.1)

Comment: Can you provide a little more info on the use and need for the second router? And by blocked do you mean that you just don't know the admin credentials to the config page?  If so, MOST routers from an ISP have a sticker with the default values on it.  Also is there are reason you can't/won't just reset the edge router (ISP one) via the reset button normally found on the back of the router near the power plug port?

Comment: Hi linuxdev2013, the second router i was told by my (ISP) that i have to have to port forward in a second router for my NVR and IP cameras to work remotely.I told them my problem with the address range . they said there is nothing they can do . and wont let me do anything with router 1.and the sticker with the default values on it did not work? Will a reset will change my address Range? i have power cycled router 1 is that how my problem started? even if i fix it, how do I prevent it from happening again? the Nvr has a Ddns active. do i need another Ddns on router 2 also?

Comment: The location is a business so i have to be careful not to make more problems i can only be out internet for maybe a hour.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Help. :)

**Answer part 1: Connecting two routers wired to create a single LAN**
http://routersetup.blogspot.com/2007/08/connecting-two-routers-wired.html

**Answer part 2: Multiple Router Port Forwarding Guide**

https://www.lorextechnology.com/self-serve/multiple-router-port-forwarding-guide/R-sc4900116

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: NVR Setup Questions? 
(Spectrum Cable Company)

Business Name: xxxxxxxxxx
Commercial Account Number: XXXXXXXXX (Spectrum Cable Company)
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Glendale NY 11385
ISP Router 1 (Spectrum) CM MAC: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: How do I set up a second router behind the ISP router for port forwarding to NVR cameras?
• I was told before by another tech support I had to use a second router to do port forwarding?
• Do you the ISP have to make changes in router 1 to make port forwarding work?
• I was told as a customer I cannot make changes to router 1?
• The network cable connection between routers is Wan-to-Lan or Lan-to-Lan?
• Do I need to turn off DHCP on router 2?
• I need (router 2) IP to be 192.168.1.xxx same network as (router 1) 192.168.1.1?

Comment: • My NVR has an active DDns do I need anything more to protect this setup from ISP IP changes?
• Can you send me a clear written guide or link FAQ for this type 2 router setup for NVR Port forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the setup on the ISP's router, or doing some dodgy convoluted switching a simple router is not capable of, you can't.  You can't have 2 devices with the same IP address on the same subnet.

You may be able to disable your second routers DHCP server and routing capabilities and turn it into a dumb switch - but you will still need to change forwarding in the cable router.

Comment: ok ?disable second routers DHCP server and routing capabilities and turn it into a dumb switch yes ? DMZ router 1 address so i can Port forwarding on router 2 ? i will try later today

Comment: ok still not working More info.

Comment: • After resetting router 2 and setting static IP in same range of router 1 before connecting router 1 has made it so I can have Internet and login to both routers :) 
• Wiring routers Lan-to-Lan made all go well so far?
• Now I have to do port forwarding with DMZ on router 1 I think? Tomorrow.